# Union and set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was reading my notes and came across this example...

`A = {z: z is a number, z is ≤ 20}`
`B = {y: y is an even number}`

```
Then A U B = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
```

To my understanding `Union` means that the elements in each set are displayed in the outputted set like so

```
For example, if A = {1, 3, 5, 7} and B = {1, 2, 4, 6} then A ∪ B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

I do not understand why this is not the case in this example, is this just a typo and should the output of `A U B` end like so `17,18,19,20...n+2}` `n+2` where n is the last number given or something along those lines? i.e. 22...24...26 and so on until infinity?

So my question is, is the first example given, wrong, or am I missing something to do with unions.

Regards

Comment: Yes, $A \cup B$ should contain all the numbers $22, 24, 26, ...$.

Comment: @T.Bongers ok thank you, guess its a typo then, cheers

Comment: And perhaps $A$ (and therefore also $A\cup B$) should also contain for example $\frac{16}{7}$, $\sqrt{2}$, $\pi$, and $-42$...

Comment: OP probably meant 'natural number'

Comment: I don't think so Henning. A is all of the natural numbers. Natural numbers are counting numbers. We have A as the set of z numbers that are less than 20 so 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20

Comment: B is y is an even number, so set B is 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20 so $A \cup B$ is indeed $[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]$

Comment: It says number, meaning it could contain all negative values also, yes, props to the great lecture notes.

Comment: @usukidoll: It just says "number". Real numbers are numbers as well, although I think the lecturer *meant*  to say natural numbers.

Comment: Yes...$R$ is real, $Q$ is rational, and $C$ is complex. I think $Z$ is integer and $N$ is natural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notes seem to be incorrect.

If $A=\{z:z\in\mathbb{N}\}=\{1,2,3,4,5,\ldots\}$ and $B=\{y:y\text{ is an even number}\}$, then $A\cup B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\ldots, 22,23,\ldots,345,\ldots\}$,

that is, all elements of $A$ and $B$.

Your example is correct however.